# What is different between SQL-Server versions 2008R2 and 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, license

Dear SQL Server experts,

Can you tell me the different between **SQL-Server 2008 R2** and **SQL-Server 2012** versions? I designed my product with version **2008** but when I tried to buy a licence, Microsoft said they won't sell it anymore, buy 2012 instead.

So I need proof that our system can run with 2012. I know it's backward compatible but I need official proof. Please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few things you'll want to watch out for:

- Changes to memory manager mean some changes to some dynamic management views - https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/08/sql-server-v-next-denali-changes-to-performance-counters
- fn_virtualfilestats no longer takes -1 for parameters - https://sqlblog.org/2011/06/28/sql-server-v-next-denali-breaking-change-to-fn_virtualfilestats
- you may no longer be able to identify system databases simply by DB_ID between 1and 4 - https://sqlblog.org/2011/07/08/sql-server-v-next-denali-breaking-change-to-system-databases-database_id-db_id
- Temp tables now get negative object IDs, so make sure you don't have code that checks for object id > 0 - https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/09/sql-server-v-next-denali-breaking-change-to-temp-tables
- sys.dm_exec_sessions has a new column, authenticating_database_id

For an official list (it doesn't include all of the above items, and there may be others that aren't coming to mind):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179(v=SQL.110).aspx

You may also want to check the discontinued features page:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262

And also run the Upgrade Advisor against your instance, this is exactly what it's for:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256.aspx

Comment: LOL, you left out licensing costs

Comment: @brian the whole licensing thing is blown out of proportion. Most customers end up paying the same price unless they have CPUs with  > 4 cores.