# What is the possibility that mirroring a database will damage, corrupt, or erase either the primary or target database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, mirroring

The last time my company had tried to mirror some databases, everything worked great until one morning they came in and the primary database in one of the mirroring schemes was just blank.  They had no errors or anything to point them to a reason of why this happened.  Since then, the company has not tried mirroring since it is not great for high availability if it just kills the primary database in the mirror setup.  The mirror was on SQL-Server 2005 (most likely).  I don't have any other information other than that because of how long ago this problem occurred.

The current setup that we are going to possibly use for mirroring will consist of SQL servers 2008, 2008 r2, 2012.  Do problems like the one mentioned happen frequently or has Microsoft improved their logic enough to rule out these possibilities for the most part?  Do problems with erasing and corruption happen more frequently when the servers are on different version of SQL Server?  Has anyone else ever had a similar problem with a nailed down cause?

Any insight or expertise would be appreciated since I cannot locate anyone who has had a similar problem yet.

Comment: There is no such thing as mirroring between SQL Server *2000* and 2005.  SQL Server 2000 does not support mirroring.

Comment: I've personally setup mirroring on several servers (both 2005 and 2012) that ran perfectly with manual failovers to support "rolling-upgrades" and automatic failovers in the case of machine or network problems, and have NEVER lost data.  That is, *after all*, the point of mirroring.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll remove 2000 from the description.  I'm guessing that information was just wrong considering they were recalling stuff from a long time ago and human memory isn't as good as a written log or anything.

Comment: @MaxVernon I was posting this figuring that it was an isolated incident but I wanted backup on that fact or to see if any experts on this site have seen that problem and a possible patch that came out years ago.  You never know what you can find out until you ask.  People at the company are still weary of that but are looking to give mirroring a second chance.  They didn't lose data that time because they do nightly and weekly backups but we also don't want any random downtime caused by mirroring.

Comment: The entire point of mirroring is to minimize downtime.  In SQL Server 2005 RTM, mirroring wasn't officially supported; however since 2005 SP1, mirroring has been officially supported as a high-availability solution.

Comment: by the way, it wasn't me that downvoted your question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is the point but things don't always work as advertised.  I always look for the pros and cons of anything to assure that they work the way people say that they should.  All I'm looking for are people like you to support the fact that these problems are not typical or don't even exist and that mirroring does improve up-time.

Comment: Yeah, it was just probably another person who thought the idea was dumb.  I get it, the problem sounds strange.  I couldn't find anyone with the same problem, which is exactly why I asked the question.

Comment: @MaxVernon I wish I had more information to give the question a better foundation but I don't have a time machine.  I would place money that you're right.  Without more information, we don't know if code or something else may have caused the original problem.

Comment: What falls under the specific expertise section of allowed formatting?  I see that and the only thing I can figure would be pretty much information from an expert which besides hard facts was the other type of information I was looking for.  @MaxVernon if I rephrased the last bit to specifically ask for statistics relating to this situation, would that be enough to fix the opinion factor or should I open up a meta question to help my wording when posting questions to Stack Exchange site?  I always seem to feel like I'm on Jeopardy being asked to phrase my answer in the form of a question.

Comment: The reason we don't "like" these type of questions is they have the nasty habit of going on and on interminably without any hard answers.  I doubt anyone could make this question fit since it is difficult, if not impossible, to entirely rule out the scenario you listed.  Suffice it to say that a great many people have and still do use Mirroring to great effect.

Comment: Alright, rather than try to reword this, I'll just take your advice and call this case closed.  @MaxVernon thanks for all of your help.

Comment: I'm not attempting to steer you away from dba.stackexchange.com (or other StackExchange sites).  If you implement mirroring and have some question about how to setup something specific, or how to monitor something, etc., please do not be afraid to ask!

Comment: @MaxVernon After watching videos and reading up on the matter, setting it up doesn't sound like it will be that hard or even take that long once we get the servers in place.  I see things like [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20130/what-is-different-between-sql-server-versions-2008r2-and-2012) and realize that there could be problems we haven't thought about and of course if anyone at the company has other worries they have to be addressed.  I like using the StackExchange sites but like this, I sometimes find it hard to ask what I want to ask if I can at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate that you are looking for anecdotes about the *experience* of using mirroring; however this site is not really the place for opinion.

Having said that, you may find the following excerpt from Microsoft.com regarding database mirroring helpful:

Database mirroring is a simple strategy that offers the following benefits:

- Increases availability of a database.

> In the event of a disaster, in high-safety mode with automatic failover, failover quickly brings the standby copy of the database online (without data loss). In the other operating modes, the database administrator has the alternative of forcing service (with possible data loss) to the standby copy of the database.

- Increases data protection.

> Database mirroring provides complete or almost complete redundancy of the data, depending on whether the operating mode is high-safety or high-performance.
>
> A database mirroring partner running on SQL Server 2008 Enterprise or later versions automatically tries to resolve certain types of errors that prevent reading a data page. The partner that is unable to read a page requests a fresh copy from the other partner. If this request succeeds, the unreadable page is replaced by the copy, which usually resolves the error. For more information, see [Automatic Page Repair (Availability Groups/Database Mirroring).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677167.aspx)

- Improves the availability of the production database during upgrades.

> To minimize downtime for a mirrored database, you can sequentially upgrade the instances of SQL Server that are hosting the failover partners. This will incur the downtime of only a single failover. This form of upgrade is known as a rolling upgrade. For more information, see [Install a Service Pack on a System with Minimal Downtime for Mirrored Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497962.aspx).

Paul Randal's sqlskills.com blog offers an excellent set of articles about mirroring at http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/database-mirroring/

Glenn Berry offers up some pertinent tips for running mirroring at http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/sql-server-database-mirroring-tips-and-tricks-part-1/

Comment: Really, I was hoping for a, "Yes, we had that problem, it was patched in KB#####."  That would be some nice hard evidence that you could show anybody and there would be no further questions.  I was definitely looking for anything else that would serve as the next best thing which would be other experts experience.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest looking at the *many* knowledge base articles on support.microsoft.com perhaps by doing the following search https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sql+server+mirroring+site%3Asupport.microsoft.com

Comment: I have been trying to do tons of research on the topic since my experience is very limited in this regard.  It seems like all of the sources you have linked (which are great BTW) agree with everything else I have read so far.  I will definitely keep doing more research on the subject.  Thanks for the duckduckgo link and everything else.  I haven't seen that site before.

Comment: I plan on marking this as the answer if nobody miraculously comes up with a solid example and fix/patch within a couple hours.  Your advice and information are probably the best for the case.  Flute stuff happens all of the time with computers of all sorts and are typically fixed with a quick reboot.  My educated guess is that this was merely a fluke.

Comment: @Joe You could also argue against the company's decision to not use mirroring on the grounds that it was undocumented. (What version did they use when the issue appeared? What was the exact setup? What did the after-incident investigation show? If they have no documents as you say (they can vaguely remember the incident, not even the version!), then here is your argument. "I don't use airplanes because one of my flights 10 years ago was cancelled" is not like something that would stand on logical examination.

Comment: @ypercube - of course with the proviso that *going forward*, everything *will* be documented.

Comment: @ypercube and Max, Yes, some sort of documentation would have been nice.  From the sound of it, they were only mirroring for a couple of weeks, that happened and they haven't touched it since.  I don't think I am going to have to argue anything moving forward considering all the documentation and everything Max has linked all support that mirroring typically helps prevent data loss, not the opposite.  I'm merely doing this for exploratory purposes to prevent knee jerk reactions.  Your reasoning is pretty solid and fairly funny.